# Spring Boot Logback - Pattern Customization

Tags: spring-boot, logback

The default spring-boot's logback default pattern is this:

```
<property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN:-%clr(%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}"/>
```

Reference is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml)

It's great! I don't want to override it, but all I need is to customize it, let's say to add the line number. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

From [the Logback docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#line):

> **L / line**
>
> Outputs the line number from where the logging request was issued.

So, if you add `%line` to the existing pattern you'll get the line number from which each log event was emitted.

It's worth noting the caveat from the Logback docs though:

> Generating the line number information is not particularly fast. Thus, its use should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue.